# Change theme menu css for WooCommerce pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

Hi I am trying to target the navigation CSS on all of my woocommerce pages to change it from (the parent css) white to black. I basically want all the menu items to be black on all shop pages.

```
.woocommerce #top-menu-nav #top-menu li a{ color: #000000 !important; }
.woocommerce #top-menu-nav #top-menu li a:hover { color: #cea54a !important; }
```

However, it only displays on the product category page but actually not on any of the shop pages. Is there something else i should add to the above to reflect this change?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the elements of your menu on woocommerce pages, you should try something like this (assuming that **`#top-menu`** is the ID of your menu:

```
body.woocommerce #top-menu a,
body.woocommerce-page #top-menu a  { 
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks :)